# how to check two maps are equal in dart

Tags: dart

Is it possible to check two maps are equals or not like `java equals`?

```
void main() {
  Map map1 = {'size': 38, 'color': 'red'};
  Map map2 = {'size': 38, 'color': 'red'};

  if(map1== map2){//both keys and values
    print('yes');
  }else{
    print('no');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found `mapEquals`.

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    
    void main() {
      Map map1 = {'size': 38, 'color': 'red'};
      Map map2 = {'size': 38, 'color': 'red'};
      
    
      if(mapEquals(map1, map2)){
        print('yes');
      }else{
        print('no');
      }
    }
```

The `mapEquals` function is a utility function from the 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' package in Flutter. It is used to compare two maps for equality. This function returns true if both maps have the same keys and their corresponding values are also equal, otherwise, it returns false.

In the given code snippet, you have two maps: `map1` and `map2`. Both maps have the same keys ('size' and 'color') and their corresponding values (38 and 'red') are also equal.

The `mapEquals(map1, map2)` function is called to compare these maps. Since both maps are equal, the function returns true and 'yes' will be printed as the output. If the maps were not equal, 'no' would have been printed.

Comment: If the maps contain other maps then this method will not work. In other words this is a first level comparison only.

Comment: downvoted because the question specifically asks for 'map equality in dart' whereas this answer only works if the user is developing a flutter app.

Comment: @Alex.F Nobody asked about deep structure equality? That's a very specific requirement.

Answer (score 31):

For Flutter, if you have a nested Map and you need to check its equality with another nested object in terms of key and value mappings use :

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

if(DeepCollectionEquality().equals(map1, map2)) {
  print('Maps are equal');
} else {
  print('Maps are not equal');
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Use `MapEquality().equals(Object a, Object b)` from package [`collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection).

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

MapEquality().equals(map1, map2)
```

See [the description](https://pub.dev/packages/collection#equality)

Comment: It doesn't compare nested maps. `DeepCollectionEquality` does.

Comment: Deprecated in 2023

Comment: @GenError Not deprecated, just moved.

Comment: @RustamG Why would you want to do that? That's a very specific requirement.

Answer (score 7):

[`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) provides a [`mapsEqual`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/mapsEqual.html) function to compare `Map`s (and similar functions for `List`s and `Set`s).  It has no dependence on Flutter and can be used in any Dart project.

Example:

```dart
// https://pub.dev/packages/quiver
// "flutter pub add quiver"
// https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/quiver.collection-library.html

import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

// Class Foo does not override its "==" operator.
// This two Foo objects are "equal" according to "=="
// if and only if they are "the same object".

class Foo {
  final int x;

  Foo(this.x);
}

// Class Bar override its "==" operator so two Bar objects
// are "equal" according to "==" if they "are the same value", in
// this case, if the value of their field "x" is the same.
// This is called "having value semantics".

class Bar {
  final int x;

  Bar(this.x);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => (other is Bar && x == other.x);

  @override
  int get hashCode => x;
}

void testMapIdentityAndEquality() {
  // Integers are "equal" if they "are the same value" ("value semantics")

  final mapInt1 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3};
  final mapInt2 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3};

  // Foo objects are "equal" only if they "are the same object".

  final mapFoo1 = {'x': Foo(1), 'y': Foo(2), 'z': Foo(3)};
  final mapFoo2 = {'x': Foo(1), 'y': Foo(2), 'z': Foo(3)};

  // Bar objects are "equal" if they "are the same value" ("value semantics")

  final mapBar1 = {'x': Bar(1), 'y': Bar(2), 'z': Bar(3)};
  final mapBar2 = {'x': Bar(1), 'y': Bar(2), 'z': Bar(3)};

  // Identity and equality of maps holding elements with value semantics.

  assert(identical(mapInt1, mapInt1), "a map is (evidently) IDENTICAL to itself");
  assert(mapInt1 == mapInt1, "a map that is the same object is also EQUAL to itself ('==' defaults to object identity)");

  assert(!identical(mapInt1, mapInt2), "a map is NOT IDENTICAL to another map");
  assert(mapInt1 != mapInt2, "a map is NOT EQUAL to another map, even if the map content is 'the same' and has value semantics");
  assert(mapsEqual(mapInt1, mapInt2), "QUIVER EQUALITY says the maps are EQUAL if map content is 'the same' and has value semantics");

  assert(!identical(mapFoo1, mapFoo2), "a map is NOT IDENTICAL to another map");
  assert(mapFoo1 != mapFoo2, "a map is NOT EQUAL to another map, especially if the map content does not have value semantics");
  assert(!mapsEqual(mapFoo1, mapFoo2), "QUIVER EQUALITY says the maps are NOT EQUAL if the map content 'looks the same' but does not have value semantics");

  assert(!identical(mapBar1, mapBar2), "a map is NOT IDENTICAL to another map");
  assert(mapBar1 != mapBar2, "a map is NOT EQUAL to another map, even if the map content is 'the same' and has value semantics");
  assert(mapsEqual(mapBar1, mapBar2), "QUIVER EQUALITY says the maps are EQUAL if map content is 'the same' and has value semantics"); // what we want

  // More cases

  assert(!mapsEqual(
      <dynamic, dynamic>{'x': Bar(1), 'y': Foo(1)},
      <dynamic, dynamic>{'x': Bar(1),'y': Foo(1)}), 
  "QUIVER EQUALITY says the maps are NOT EQUAL if the map content 'looks the same' but at least some of the elements do not have value semantics");
  assert(!mapsEqual(mapBar1, mapFoo1), "Not even the same type");
}

void main() {
  testMapIdentityAndEquality();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any of these answer didn't worked for me.

I tried map1.toString() == map2.toString() and it worked.

Comment: Comparing string representations has a few problems: 1. The string representations are sensitive to order, which you often don't care about. 2. The string representations can be ambiguous; you could have two maps that are not the same but that have the same `.toString()` representation.

Comment: As @jamesdlin says, never do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Map v1 = {'name': "ahmed", "age": 24};
    Map v2 = {'name': "ahmed", "age": 24};
    if(v1.toString() == v2.toString())
  print('yes');
    else{
      print('no');
    }
  }
```

Comment: dude, this will not work even if your keys has different order. And I'm not touching the deep-equals.

Comment: Never ever do it like this

Answer (score 0):

I tried to not use any other dependencies. You can copy/paste the following code in Dart Playground and test it.

```
void main() {
  final map1 = {'a':1, 'b':3};
  final map2 = {'a':1, 'b':3};
  final map3 = {'b':3, 'a':1};
  final map4 = {'b':3, 'a':1, 'c':1};
  bool result = _mapEquals(map1, map2);
  print(result); // true
  result = _mapEquals(map1, map3);
  print(result); // true
  result = _mapEquals(map1, map4);
  print(result); // false
}

bool _mapEquals(Map<String, int> map1, Map<String, int> map2) {
  if (map1.keys.length != map2.keys.length) return false;

  for (String k in map1.keys) {
    if (!map2.containsKey(k)) return false;
    if (map1[k] != map2[k]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: This only works if the map values have value semantics, i.e. react well to operator `==` (as integers do). Once the values are arbitrary objects, you need to give them a `==` unless you `==` to perform the default "object identity check".