# How to Compare two maps in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two maps with same data (key, value) but I can't compare them because they are not equal? I have tried all the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765518/how-to-check-two-maps-are-equal-in-dart) but none of them gave true except the one that I have to change the map to string( which I know it's not the right thing). So why they are not equal and what is the right way to compare them to each other?

```
Map map1 = {28: 67, 33: 60};
Map attributesIndex = {118: {28: 66, 33: 58}, 120: {28: 66, 33: 59}, 121: {28: 66, 33: 60}, 122: {28: 66, 33: 61}, 126: {28: 66, 33: 65}, 127: {28: 67, 33: 59}, 128: {28: 67, 33: 60}, 130: {28: 67, 33: 62}};
```

And the tests are below:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
attributesIndex.entries.forEach((element) {
    if(DeepCollectionEquality().equals(element.value, map1)) {
        print('Maps are equal');
    } else {
        print('Maps are not equal');
    }
})
```

This returns false.

```
import 'package:collection/equality.dart';
attributesIndex.entries.forEach((element) {
    if(MapEquality().equals(element.value, map1)){
        print('Maps are equal');
    } else {
        print('Maps are not equal');
    }
})
```

This returns false;

```
attributesIndex.entries.forEach((element) {
    if(mapEquals(element.value, map1)){
        print('Maps are equal');
    }else{
        print('Maps are not equal');
    }
})
```

This returns false

```
attributesIndex.entries.forEach((element) {
    if(element.value.toString() == map1.toString()){
        print('Maps are equal');
    } else{
        print('Maps are not equal');
    }
})
```

this returns true, but I think it's not the right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check two maps are equal in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765518/how-to-check-two-maps-are-equal-in-dart)

Comment: this answer work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/61765671/10595176

Comment: @OMiShah I have added that question in my answer as you may see, So I'm looking for an explanation instead of a working answer. because as I explained in my question one of these answers is working for me but I think it's not a good way to solve it.

Comment: Please provide your actual code. Your two examples are not legal.  After fixing the various syntax errors, the `DeepCollectionEquality()`, `MapEquality()`, and `mapEquals` methods all work for me.

Comment: Unless overridden, == is checking for *object identity equality*.  map1 and map2 are two different objects.  If you change one, the other doesn't change.  If you had said "map1 = {...}; map2 = map1;" then changing one changes "the other", and then "==" will be true.

Comment: @jamesdlin I Have added more info please

Comment: @user2682025 Please post, a complete (runnable), reproducible example.  You again clearly are not doing that since your code still has syntax errors (missing semicolons).  I should be able to copy and paste your code verbatim and reproduce the problem you're encountering.  After fixing your syntax errors, I still see "Maps are equal" printed once for each approach.

Comment: This question still does not provide debugging details or a reproducible example, and likely is caused by a typo or other information that the OP is withholding.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet works. It is shown below.

1. All imports should be at the top.
2. You had syntax errors.

For the second one, equality.dart is depreciated. Try and keep your enviorment updated.

```
        import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

        Map map1 = {28: 67, 33: 60};
        Map map2 = {28: 67, 33: 60};
    
        if (DeepCollectionEquality().equals(map1, map2)) {
          print('Maps are equal');
        } else {
          print('Maps are not equal');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know the imports should be at the top I added it that way to separate the ways. And for your answer it didn't work. I will try to update my question to give more info about the maps.

Comment: @user2682025 That's quite odd. I just ran it on flutter. Are you sure you are up to date? It's quite possible something else is the problem.