# Why .contains not checking in List<Map>?

Tags: flutter, dart

function:

```
var mapList = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "zein"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "john"},
];

print(mapList.contains({"id": "1", "name": "zein"}));
```

Result: `false`

The list actually contains the value. Why is it still false?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to check two maps are equal in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61765518/how-to-check-two-maps-are-equal-in-dart)

Comment: Not, the answer is not related to list

Comment: @enzo isn't the OP is trying to find if a map object exists in a multi map objects list?

Comment: @OMiShah Just use the link I've sent to compare each map in the list with the map you want to find. Five seconds of searching shows that comparing maps in Dart is different from usual.

Comment: solutions are welcome

Comment: as @enzo suggested: `mapEquals` - this is what you need

Comment: ............hmm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @enzo, you can use the `mapEquals` to compare two map objects as:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  var mapList = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "zein"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "john"}
  ];

  var toCheck = {"id": "1", "name": "zein"};

  print(mapList.any((e) => mapEquals(e, toCheck))); // true
  
}
```

Alternatively, you can iterate the list and check as:

```
mapList.forEach((e) {
  print(mapEquals(e, toCheck));
});
```

Comment: yes, he should use `mapEquals` but not in the way you say - instead of `mapList.forEach` it should be used with `mapList.any` for example - OP wants to know if given list contains value or not

Answer (score 2):

Just try these lines of code:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = [
  {"id": "1", "name": "zein"},
  {"id": "2", "name": "john"},
];

mapList.forEach((element) {print(element.keys.contains("id"));});

mapList.forEach((element) {print(element.values.contains("zein"));});
```

It doesn't work because you need to do it separately.